# fluid layout - text sliding off the screen when resizing window

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure how to fix this.

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ccX5u/

Everything looks pretty good minus the image on the left side.  But my main issue is that when I'm shrinking the browser window the `user name | Log off` slide off to the side.  I really want to make this as fluid as possible.

What do I need to change to get this behavior?

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
.title-wrapper {
    padding-top: 20px; 
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 98%;
    display:block;
}


#title-area {
    background: url('image.png')center center no-repeat;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    width: 270px;
    height: 100px;
}

#menuTitleThin{
    position:absolute;
    padding-top:10px;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right:10px;
    font-size:20px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #d95936;
    width:82%;


}

#menuLoginInfo {
    float:right;
    font-size:20px;
    position:relative;
}
#menuLoginInfo a {
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* menu
----------------------------------------------------------*/
    ul#menu {
        font-size: 1.0em;
        font-weight: 600;
        margin: 50px 0 5px;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: left;
    }

    ul#menu li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    ul#menu li a {
        background: none;
        color: #999;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul#menu li a:hover {
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

</style>
        <div class="title-wrapper">
            <div id="title-area">
                <span id="title"/>
            </div>
            <span id="menuTitleThin">Services - <b>Title</b> 
                <span id="menuLoginInfo"><span>user name</span> | <span>Log off</span></span>
            </span>

                <span>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li>test</li>
                        <li>test 2</li>
                        <li>test 3</li>
                    </ul>
                </span>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of the trouble with floating elements in a fluid setup.

You can use [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to set the width of `#menuTitleThin` which will allow the menu to be fluid and still leave room for the `#title-area` on the left. Then you just need to float `#menuTitleThin` appropriately to allow for a smooth re-size:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ccX5u/6/)**

```
#title-area {
    background: red url('image.png')center center no-repeat; /* added red for demo only */
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    width: 270px;
    height: 100px;
}
#menuTitleThin {
    float: left; /* change here */
    padding-top:10px;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right:10px;
    font-size:20px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #d95936;
    width: calc(100% - 295px); /* change here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the following line:

```
<span id="menuTitleThin">Services - <b>Title</b>
```

Using the CSS rule

```
position: absolute;
```

You cannot set absolute positioning to an **inline** element.

To fix it, simply add the the following rule:

```
#menuTitleThin{
position:absolute;
padding-top:10px;
margin-left:15px;
margin-right:10px;
font-size:20px;
border-bottom: 3px solid #d95936;
width:82%;

/*******Add this rule********/
display:block;

}
```

Changing the display mode to block will fix it.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccX5u/1/)

Comment: I tried that and when the image actually shows up on the left hand side all the text gets pushed over that.  So I need the image to be displayed on the left and the line to span the rest of the page with the "User Name | Log off" display on the right but not to slide off when the browser gets adjusted.

Comment: Can you add the real URL of the image to the fiddle so I can see what you are talking about? Your local URL won't work in JSFiddle.

Comment: Does this work?  http://jsfiddle.net/ccX5u/2/

My company is blocking jsFiddle for whatever reason so I can't really see it either.  The image size is 263x73 if that gives you any help.

Comment: Do you have to do this without tables? I can fix this quite easily using tables, if that is allowed.

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ccX5u/3/ This is done using tables.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to do some thing like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/ccX5u/7/

```
.title-wrapper {position: relative; /*NEW*/}
#menuTitleThin {right: 0; /*NEW*/}
```

**Position: relative** controls absolute positioning base on how you place it...in this case i added to the right (right: 0). I only fixed the top menu I figure thats what you where asking for.